# Cannot get menu selection to run a function. C++

Tags: c++, function, menu

I wish to create code that will call a function from a menu selection. I wish the menu to choose the action of converting kilos and pounds. The menu selection in my current code is not accomplishing this task. How can I get the menu selection to work? I want it to convert kilos to pounds, convert pounds to kilos, and quit the program. The menu selections should loop with the selection of 3 to quit the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
void displayMenu();
int getChoice(int min, int max);
double kilosToPounds(double);
double poundsToKilos(double);

/*****     main     *****/
int main()
{
    double weight = 0;
    int choice = 0;

    displayMenu();

    cout << "Please choose a function: ";
    cin >> choice;

    choice = getChoice(1, 3);
    
    while (choice == 1)
    {
        double kilosToPounds(weight);
    }
    while (choice == 2)
    {
        double kilosToPounds(weight);
    }
    while (choice == 3);
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

/*****     displayMenu     *****/
void displayMenu()
{
    int padding = 8;

    cout << "Program to convert weights:\n\n"
        << right
        << setw(padding) << "" << "1. Convert kilograms to pounds\n"
        << setw(padding) << "" << "2. Convert pounds to kilograms\n"
        << setw(padding) << "" << "3. Quit\n";

}


/*****     getChoice     *****/
// THIS IS THE SAME FUNCTION YOU WROTE EARLIER IN THIS SET
// OF LAB EXERCISES. JUST FIND IT AND PASTE IT HERE. 
int getChoice(int min, int max)
{
    int choice;
    // Get and validate the input
    cin >> choice;
    while (choice < min || choice > max)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input. Enter an choice between 1 & 3: ";
    }
    return choice;
}

/*****     kilosToPounds     *****/
double kilosToPounds(double weight)
{
    double kilo = weight / 2.2;
    cout << "This item weighs " << kilo << " kilos.\n";
    return 0;
}

/*****    poundsToKilos     *****/
double poundsToKilos(double weight)
{
    double pounds = weight * 2.2;
    cout << "This item weighs " << pounds << " pounds.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Double click on the grey bar to the left of your code line numbering to set a `breakpoint`. Then, when you press the play button (to run your code), the code stop on that line. Then, press any of the arrow buttons to step over, one-step, or step into different commands. At the bottom left will be a window with variables. You can expand classes to see current values. Learn how to use your debugger!!!

Comment: It has the right variable at line 27 choice = getChoice(1, 3)
But it just stops there.

Comment: Click on the "step into" button on getChoice, not the "step over" button.

Comment: Duh! I had no cout to prompt for the weight so I didn't realize it was waiting for input! Thanks @John for the debugger tips, that solved it for me. The value for 'choice' was there, but it also needed a value for 'weight'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revisited this question and was able to create a solution using a case statement and a while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int choice = 0;
double weight = 0;
double pounds = 0;
double kilo = 0;

int displayMenu()
{
    int padding = 8;

    cout << "Program to convert weights:\n\n"
        << right
        << setw(padding) << "" << "1. Convert kilograms to pounds" << endl
        << setw(padding) << "" << "2. Convert pounds to kilograms" << endl
        << setw(padding) << "" << "3. Quit\n" << endl;
    cout << "Please choose a function: ";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

int getChoice(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Enter your weight in kilograms: ";
        cin >> weight;
        kilo = weight / 2.2;
        cout << "This item weighs " << kilo << " pounds.\n" << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Enter your weight in pounds: ";
        cin >> weight;
        pounds = weight * 2.2;
        cout << "This item weighs " << pounds << " kilos.\n" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "\nGoodbye!\n";
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (choice < 3)
    {
        displayMenu();
        getChoice(choice);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you want to use a while loop here?

```
    while (choice == 1)
    {
        double kilosToPounds(weight);
    }
```

2. If choice == 1, how and when will you escape the loop?

Also, you might want to do something with the value you are computing:

```
        double weightInPounds = kilosToPounds(weight);
```

Comment: Good points. But I think they are off the mark concerning OPs problem. Comments by @John seem very plausible to me - though a little guessy.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I see how while was causing an infinite loop. I changed it to if but I cannot get the function to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code:

1. If you already have `getChoice` function which takes user's input, why are taking user's input before call to the `getChoice` function?

```cpp
    cout << "Please choose a function: ";
    cin >> choice;   // <-- not needed
```

2. Why do you use `while` loop if you only want to check for a certain condition? Use `if` statement instead.

```cpp
if (choice == 1) {...}
```

instead of

```cpp
while (choice == 1) {...}
```

3. When calling a function, you don't need to specify its return type.

```cpp
auto pounds = kilosToPounds(weight);
```

or just

```cpp
kilosToPounds(weight);
```

instead of

```cpp
double kilosToPounds(weight);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEADZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEQkgBykADqgWE6rR6hibmvv6BdLb2Tkau7l6KypiqQQwEzMQEIcamFkoqanQZWQQxji5uHt4Kmdm5YQX15XaV8dVeAJSKqAbEyBwA5FIAzHbIhlgA1OKjOup1xJjMRnPY4gAMAIJjE1OYs/PqRiJ4Putb2wYBotO0q5gKPsyD03Xoc7I7VwD0v9MAGIGWhpOjTHzEVBEAgATx8TyuADdUHh0NN8M9hLCALJaAwQLpfK52AjTYCYHIIVGDCCk6ZGOykab004ADyJo2%2B23QfWc7GmAGs8Kx/AAVVAABT62gUEF5Bn5mE53IVSohMvQCglAGkRf55Xz2Cqrn8AFQWi3Ta3W052G3Wy0W34k%2BgM5h2QmmgDs3IdaoFAHdMHhgAgyXMACLTTibYk7B305DUvBvKMx%2BO7BM2zE%2BbF42gEk0/bPWtAGCPzOY6WaSSSS9jMJTTZOofyHZjTKggsGmWuSTNXB2t1OHdMUqk0zAQTjM0bFrPbYd9Ss6avTKysQelllUaYQEdp0aR9OcIk78S%2BocOm3C0XaqWauXB0PhhcOy8nnfKZt4PcHlMjxPY9pkkc8lxtS8/Rva073FR8QS1CAXzDAh30g70vwg60f0OP990PMdj3TedMw/K8dwdZYCH6WhpjjLlr2tT8fSw80nRvXN83xG8nTNF0dhRNEMTwLFmFxfEvR%2BCjsJZN0XnQfA7nTTxt1k8tV3XKR6yhYBiFWaYiBbOgkTcMkUPDBQQHEABWHRaFs%2BztKYm9q3XYhXwIFyPyreZ3kpQMIAUpTgC6I41z85y63CrS604AA6aY9FoUzsiFfU9NWBRDNQDVEIURyHLrbzIN8mslAIQLgrsUKYsi4rorc%2Bq60S5LUrJPx8py9LRUyowCrsoqB0o0qIvKgKguYRSarCpqayiyQ6vmutRkSgBFAxCEK5zGJLXZMNNPbfj4m8Jx0QDDgdPiBO2f5pjFAAJABJBhphe%2B6HuwaYGG2HEvsBABVBwdDFJ6AHkHGmABNMGAemAB1AAlMGxS%2B7BtkR6wnuwRG3shx73oYbAxT%2BAEwcBaZrG2aRpmwAANHGdBe7AGESgApAGGDFIEnocaMnu57Y%2BemSVti5r6BemT7EewRLXTJM6LrpN1GVoZlWWYDkfWg60kwuo5o04MibTugBxSlphEdEkTYNFmAIQ4CAQPDaB8CsXMDBARUOACp3Chl7UvNdvRrQiji%2B9lwPInWbw0pb%2ByelLbfROw3YIRLsHoNxLbosPXEqzAtBjWszGmUYQH7Y3mIOndqNolsLsHGvF2OjiHTgh9pS6q6nRugNDg7iUu9lQ1FSDENUPAqCXP7nrcvTCyyQBSR4oHXb1JXePtLFL3ssITAjGmCzsu0%2BO4K36KO/i7bivXqjKXrhjuRYo6TptTrZV1fVsp7y0%2B6NQ4H8tRf3vKPdUi8p4yX9AAvKsoDZHwnuGaYZpQKryrsZCsF9JA71EiyB2h9j79njkAk%2BZUiEkOvoNHaMc67EDok/ViQweisBAEMGyQxSCmCGJsDhqBWFrhkHId4fQBhjkkKMTgHCCCsJ4V0HogoQA2RXmYUY3pNjehst6TgnhNicBsmYAxQhWHcA4VwnhpA%2BFDA4VZTYpBpHcKYaQOAsAYCIBQKgIwPhvZkAoAeDxXj2DuGAAoB4PgFDUgIKQKgIoHbECshAZwMiOHODsFkWErDJGkDQEYIwWgCBg1oKwdJDjSBYFOKIdgSTSl4GWGkUyVkSmYDZKkCswxzGkmUFU1geBnD6WILCPQWAMlSI8kYYZPQaD0CYGwDgPB%2BCCGEKIFAcg5BCB6VZSAPRUA%2BGKLQBpABafZHwowSEETITgmTCipF2ZobQjRTCzisBUOICRBB%2BACLs%2B5bzIi7OeVUdws4rm9lKA0fQeRBBAt2SC1osR/kQpaF8wFLQ/kdABT0BQIjBhcGYaw9hnCqmWLZJ4Mw%2ByzDcHJMgZA%2B4CDEBBIKMKEBcCEBILWCRzI9CeO8ays8SUVkyCkUkuRpAFGqPijZIxQwTGkDGTZWxZjeGsOsSAWx9jZFONcRAJAK407kEoNkgJ1RHn4CIACqJdBGAsEqXMwM%2BkfDjIlXi%2BVFjWFjE4EfQgCBphEpJWSilVKIA0rpV0AVDihXOymtUQkEqpUyrlQSxVihlV2MFfIkA3BvTxVGGYSQABOSQ3AvCcBzZ4bgoxRi8BYUMUYpj41WOTaGnFQxJA1pKZYkNsieipQCBobgQA%3D)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I am still not getting a return from the functions.

Answer (score 0):

See Below,

```
       cout << "Please choose a function: ";
       cin >> choice;
```

remove the cin>>choice; because you are getting choice from getChoice(int,int); function. so it has no need here.

and In getChoice(int,int) function,

```
    int getChoice(int min, int max)
    {
      int choice;
      // Get and validate the input
      cin >> choice;
      while (choice < min || choice > max)
      {
          cout << "Invalid input. Enter an choice between 1 & 3: ";
      }
       return choice;
    }
```

You have No input in the while loop, So if you enter choice in less than min or grater than max the loop goes infinite because there is no changes in choice variable.So take input in the loop.

In main()

if the choice equal to 1 or 2 it goes to infinite loop because of this

```
             while (choice == 1)..
```

and In main()

```
             double kilosToPounds(weight);
```

it is not the way to call the function and you did not have no weight to calculate.

full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


void displayMenu();
int getChoice(int,int);
double kilosToPounds(double);
double poundsToKilos(double);


int main()
{
    double weight = 0;
    int choice = 0;

    displayMenu();

    cout << "Please choose a function: ";
    choice = getChoice(1, 3);

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        cin>>weight;
        kilosToPounds(weight);
    }
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        cin>>weight;
        kilosToPounds(weight);
    }
    if (choice == 3);
    {
        return 0;
    } 
 }


void displayMenu()
{
    int padding = 8;

    cout << "Program to convert weights:\n\n"
         << right
         << setw(padding) << "" << "1. Convert kilograms to pounds"<<endl
         << setw(padding) << "" << "2. Convert pounds to kilograms"<<endl
         << setw(padding) << "" << "3. Quit"<<endl;

}


int getChoice(int min, int max)
{
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    while (choice < min || choice > max)
    {
       cout << "Invalid input. Enter an choice between 1 & 3: ";
       cin >> choice;
    }
    return choice;
}

double kilosToPounds(double weight)
{
     double kilo = weight / 2.2;
     cout << "This item weighs " << kilo << " kilos.\n"<<endl;
     return 0;
}


double poundsToKilos(double weight)
{
    double pounds = weight * 2.2;
    cout << "This item weighs " << pounds << " pounds."<<endl;;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If there is another answer with the same content, you upvote it, not duplicate it.

Comment: @NutCracker Sorry, Other answers does' t Have some points about the int getChoice(int min, int max); function, so why I am added my answer but Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I see your points about the while loop, I changed it to if loops. I also fixed my function calls. However, the issue still persists my menu selection is not working.

Comment: @RyanDunnion Did you change the getchoice() function by adding cin in the while loop

Comment: @RyanDunnion see getchoice () function in full code

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthan It stopped because it was waiting for input. I didn't write a cout to prompt for the weight. So I had no idea why it stopped.

Comment: @Ryan Dunnion  what is the meaning of stopped here. The execution Is completely stopped or it is waiting for input ?. Input does not require a output. output is for Inform the user to give input

Comment: Yes @Srilakshmikanthan that is exactly what happened. The program was waiting for input and I neglected to add a cout statement to prompt for it.